# symbols in legend loose edge

Tags: plotting, legending

I make my own symbols for plotting:

```
onesymb =  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], Black]], Red,    Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 18]

twosymb =  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], Black]], White, Polygon[Dynamic@     Flatten[Table[{{Cos[i*2 \[Pi]/ns], Sin[i*2 \[Pi]/ns]}, 
    0.4 {Cos[(i + 0.5)*2 \[Pi]/ns],  Sin[(i + 0.5)*2 \[Pi]/ns]}}, {i, ns + 1}], 1]]},  ImageSize -> 26]
```

but when I use them:

```
ListPlot[{{{0.5, 0.5}, {2, 2}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 4}}}, PlotMarkers -> {onesymb,twosymb}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}, PlotLegends - Placed[LineLegend[{{"one", "two"}},    LabelStyle -> {Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 20},    LegendMarkerSize -> 20], Right]]
```

I notice that, in the legend, the symbols loose their (black) edge. How to repair this in Mathematica 12? thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `EdgeForm[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], Black, Opacity[1]]]` when you define you markers.

[image]

You can also use `EdgeForm[Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], Opacity[1, Black]]]`.